# Why -editable is not working in iwidgets (tcl/tk)?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, incr-tcl

I was trying to use iwidgets in some GUI and I want to make combobox non-editable. As per activetcl documentation, the `-editable` option is mentioned for combobox and yet it is not working.

```
combobox $frm_sat1.c2 \
    -textvariable [itcl::scope type] \
    -state normal -entries {"1 opt" "2 opt"} -editable 0;
```

Comment: Which documentation exactly? I've looked through ActiveState's docs and I can't see any combobox widget that supports the `-entries` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself.
"-state restricted" works

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$frm_sat1.c2.lwchildsite.efchildsite.arrowBtn configure -state disabled
```